# Joomla 4x - orreride wrongly using default file

Tags: joomla, overriding, templating, joomla4

Hello and happy new year !

I started using Joomla 4 for a new project after using Joomla 3 for a few years.

(im using shaper helix ultimate template)

I have been doing everything the same i did on joomla 3 (and made 4 differents websites without problems), so i guess something changed in joomla 4 and i can't grasp what.

And i'm facing a problem to which i have not found any usefull answer yet, let me explain :

I have a category "What-to-do" that have a child category "spectacles", which have 3 test articles in.

This "spectacles" category have a custom layout "yantra" set on the category options.

Category "spectacle" -> Options -> Layout : "From shaper_helixultimate template" -> yantra

What i'm trying to edit is the view which list the differents articles in a category, so i have overrided "com_content/category" creating 3 new files "yantra.php" "yantra_items.php" "yantra_children.php" in "templates\shaper_helixultimate\html\com_content\category", each one containing :

`defined ('_JEXEC') or die();

require HelixUltimate\Framework\Platform\HTMLOverride::loadTemplate();`

Then i have copied the 3 default files in "components\com_content\tmpl\category" to "templates\shaper_helixultimate\overrides\com_content\category" and then renammed them respectively "yantra.php" "yantra_items.php" "yantra_children.php"

Since the page show a , and the file im editing show the same div so i quite sure im working with the right files.

But obviously nothing i change on my custom layout "yantra.php" seems to show on the category list page.

Instead if i edit the "default.php" in the same folder my modifications are showing. (not a solution since i'm going to have different layout per category)

So the override works but use the default.php file and i can't get why.

I went to edit the menu item im using to navigate to this category view :

"Menu item type -> Category List"

"Choose a category -> Spectacles"

I see the options on this menu item that i can also choose a layout, but i have no other option than default and can't find the main layout files for this.

If i use the full link "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=15" it's using the right override file.
But if i use the link generated from the menu item "index.php/programme/spectacles" it use the defaut override.

Anybody got an idea on what's going on and what to do to solve this ?

In advance, a big thank you, i'm seeing my hairline receiding with every second im stuck with this damn problem.

Jim